# Magento category->getUrlPath() and trailing slashes

Tags: magento

we're trying to get the URL of a product within a category, and have this code:

```
$_categories = $_relatedProduct->getCategoryIds();
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]);
$url = $this->getUrl($_category->getUrlPath()).'/'.$_relatedProduct->getUrlPath();
```

The problem is that, on our development server, the call to `$category->getUrlPath()` doesn't return a value with a trailing slash, but it does on our production server. Does anybody know whether there's a config option we need to set so the returned values are consistent?

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, the issue is that the generated URLs appear like this on on development server:

http://devserver.com/category/product

but like this on the live server:

http://liveserver.com/category//product  (two slashes after category)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you have re-write rule in .htaccess on production and option to incluide / in category URLs.
So, it doubles slashes at the end )

I have the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit2: Updated answer was off base

---

Is your base URL the same on both? I'd check there - I would imagine it has a trailing slash on one of them.

Edit: You can check in core_config_data table or through the interface - I just don't have Mage on my dev computer to check!

Comment: It's not the same, no, as they're different sites, but they both have a trailing slash. However, the issue isn't there - see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer, but on another system (not Magento related) we had this double slash problem that was traced to a difference in URL rewrites and another in the Apache server configurations between the two systems. Happened so long ago I've forgotten exactly what, but I'd know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:
browse to System > Index Management and select the Catalog Url Rewrites to refresh them.
The double slash disappear.